WSO2 APIM 4.1.0 API Editing existing resources and authentication Schemes (Enable Seurity) is not working after deploying a new revision
WSO2 API Server : 4.1.0
I have initially imported the API definitions of version 1.0 having security disabled for some of the API resources. And the clients can successfully connected to version 1.0 URL.API definition has Authentication Ouath2 enabled with the key manager however under resources level the security is disabled for all.
Currently we are trying to enable the security under those resources in Staging environment, we have enabled this from publisher portal and deployed a new version. This doesn't seem to pick up the authentication schemes for the resources.
If we remove all subscriptions and then delete the API and reimport it using swagger having the security enabled for all resources, it works fine. But this approach is not feasible in the production environment as the clients are already subscribed to the version 1.0. Removing it from developer portal is not feasible.
Is this expected behavior?
Or if we change the authentication schemes of existing resources are we expected to create a new version (for eg:2.0) and deploy it and deprecate the older one? This is as well is not a easy approach in production, since then all the clients has to change the URL being used to hit the back end services.
Please help.

After changing the API Schemas, please deploy a new revision of the API to respective Gateway environments. Furthermore, when you are deploying the API, are you seeing any errors in the wso2carbon logs?
